# Use subquery result in parent query case statement

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have a `hauls` table that has columns `id` `location_id` `completed_at` and others.  I would like to add a column to the query results that has the days since the previous completed haul.  This query returns the expected results:

```sql
SELECT
    `h`.*,
    (
        SELECT
            `completed_at`
        FROM
            `hauls`
        WHERE
            `location_id` = `h`.`location_id`
            AND `completed_at` < `h`.`completed_at`
        ORDER BY
            `completed_at` DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS `previous_completed_at`
FROM
    hauls h
```

But I would like to use `DATEDIFF(h.completed_at, previous_completed_at) as days` in the parent query select statement but `previous_completed_at` cannot be found.

I realize I could use a lateral join but I need this to be MySQL 5.7 compatible.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: In mysql 8.0, you could use the window `LAG()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to wrap the entire query as a subquery:

```
SELECT tmp.*,
       DATEDIFF(tmp.`completed_at`, tmp.`previous_completed_at`) as `days`
  FROM (SELECT h.*,
               (SELECT z.`completed_at`
                  FROM `hauls` z
                 WHERE z.`location_id` = h.`location_id` AND z.`completed_at` < h.`completed_at`
                 ORDER BY z.`completed_at` DESC
                 LIMIT 1) AS `previous_completed_at`
          FROM `hauls` h) tmp 
 ORDER BY tmp.`completed_at` DESC;
```

The `*` is suboptimal, but this is one way to write the query so that it is compatible with every version of MySQL.

Be sure to add some `WHERE` clauses to these queries so that system performance does not suffer